# Binding Ember input component to control update on every key-press

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I’m building an input that I want to be able to control and validate on the fly. I have a `card-input` component, which I’ve set up to use like this:

```
{{card-input placeholder="Card number" action="handleCardNumber" value="cardNumber"}}
```

My `card-input.hbs` component looks like this:

```
{{input placeholder=placeholder value=value key-press=action}}
```

And finally my `card-input.js` component file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  classNames: ['checkout-form-group'],

  cardNumber: null,

  actions: {
    handleCardNumber (value) {
      // do some stuff with the value
      this.set('cardNumber', value)
    }
  }

});
```

Currently the value of the input is being set as `cardNumber`. Whenever I `key-press` on the `card-input`, I want to be able to control and set the `cardNumber`, which will then be updated back at the `card-input`.

Not even sure this is the best way to do things. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `cardNumber`.

```
{{card-input placeholder="Card number" action="handleCardNumber" cardNumber=cardNumber}}
```

and use it inside input helper.

```
{{input placeholder=placeholder value=cardNumber key-press=action}}
```

Comment: How can I make it so that `card-input` is reusable with multiple values, e.g. `cardNumber=cardNumber`, `cardExpiry=cardExpiry`, `cardCvc=cardCvc` and so on?

Comment: You can say `inputValue=cardNumber`  and use `inputValue` inside input helper like `value=inputValue`. as its two way binding ..inputValue will update cardNumber or cardExpiry anything you assigned

Comment: It still doesn’t seem to be updating the text I’m typing in the `card-input` with: `{{card-input placeholder="Card number" action="handleCardNumber" inputValue=cardNumber}}` and `{{input placeholder=placeholder value=inputValue key-press=action}}` in my `card-input.hbs`.

Comment: You can check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8665595e1f3a4f638c6d1e8ed2596330?openFiles=templates.components.card-input.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.card-input.hbs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal HTML5 element and only bind actions:

```
<input placeholder={{placeholder}} value={{value}} onkeypress={{action 'handleCardNumber' value='target.value'}} />
```